# Arduino compiler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, port, emscripten

Is there a way that I can use Emscripten to convert the Arduino compiler to JavaScript? Or maybe there's something else I could use to convert it, or even a version that is already in JS?

Comment: I mean like using Emscripten to take the Arduino compiler source code and convert it to JavaScript

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A working Chrome app that allows you to write code for an Arduino and upload it to the Arduino to test it. I'm doing this as a project. I just don't know how to make the compiler work in the browser.

Comment: Do you have working Arduino code?

Comment: The compiler code or code that will run on an Arduino?

Comment: After looking at the [repository for arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder) we see that it needs to handle files and call gcc. This means that you would need a working equivalent of gcc in the browser (which Emscripten isn't - Edit: I mean Emscripten doesn't run in the browser) and branch arduino-builder to use that (and compile it to javascript)... plus futher wrapping to handle files from the web interface (Edit: I mean, taking files from a file input and output a file you can save to disk).

Comment: The code that will run at Arduino.

Comment: Note, have not tried Arduino, yet. Though there are libraries which use `javascript` at Arduino https://github.com/AnnaGerber/node-ardx, see also http://stackabuse.com/how-to-program-an-arduino-with-javascript/